# RecyclerView Item position change by drag and drop method , doesn't update the item's position in ROOM database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

RecyclerView Item position change by drag and drop method , doesn't update the item's position in ROOM database, when reopening the app , the positions are all the same as they were before I try to drag and move them.

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkoutInterface{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Button btnAddWorkout;
TextView txtViewInstructions;
private WorkoutAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAddWorkout = findViewById(R.id.btnAddWorkout);
    txtViewInstructions = findViewById(R.id.txtViewInstructions);
    btnAddWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddWorkoutDialog();
        }
    });
    initRecyclerView();
    loadWorkoutList();
    updateInstructionsVisibility();
    recyclerViewAdapter.setWorkoutInterface(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(WorkoutItem workoutItem) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Workout.class);
        intent.putExtra("WORKOUT_NAME", workoutItem.getWorkoutName()); // Pass workout details
        intent.putExtra("WORKOUT_ID", workoutItem.getId());
        startActivity(intent);
}
private void showAddWorkoutDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogBackground);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_workout, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText workoutNameEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_workout_name);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String workoutName = workoutNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!workoutName.isEmpty()) {
                saveNewWorkout(workoutName);
                loadWorkoutList();
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateInstructionsVisibility();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

private void saveNewWorkout(String workoutName) {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    WorkoutItem workoutItem = new WorkoutItem();
    workoutItem.workoutName = workoutName;
    database.workoutDao().insertWorkoutItem(workoutItem);
}

public void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_workout);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new WorkoutAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new SwipeToDeleteCallback());
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper1 = new ItemTouchHelper(new DragAndDropCallback());
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    itemTouchHelper1.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

private void loadWorkoutList() {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    List<WorkoutItem> workoutList = database.workoutDao().getAllWorkoutItems();
    updateWorkoutItemPositions(workoutList);
    workoutList = database.workoutDao().getAllWorkoutItems();

    recyclerViewAdapter.setWorkoutList(workoutList);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private void updateWorkoutItemPositions(List<WorkoutItem> workoutList) {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    database.runInTransaction(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < workoutList.size(); i++) {
        WorkoutItem workoutItem = workoutList.get(i);
        workoutItem.setPosition(i); // Update the position in the WorkoutItem

        // Update the WorkoutItem in the database
        database.workoutDao().updateWorkoutItemPosition(workoutItem.getId(), workoutItem.getPosition());
    }
    });
}

private class DragAndDropCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback{
    DragAndDropCallback(){
        super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,0);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
        
        List<WorkoutItem> workoutList = recyclerViewAdapter.getWorkoutList();
        if (workoutList != null && fromPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && toPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

            WorkoutItem movedItem = workoutList.get(fromPosition);

            workoutList.remove(fromPosition);

            workoutList.add(toPosition, movedItem);

            // Notify adapter of the item movement
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

            // Update positions in the database
            updateWorkoutItemPositions(workoutList);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }
}
private class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    SwipeToDeleteCallback() {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        WorkoutItem deletedItem = recyclerViewAdapter.getWorkoutList().get(position);
        deleteItem(deletedItem);
        updateInstructionsVisibility();
    }
}
    private void deleteItem(WorkoutItem workoutItem) {
        // Remove item from RecyclerView
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        database.workoutDao().delete(workoutItem);
        recyclerViewAdapter.removeItem(workoutItem);

    }

private void updateInstructionsVisibility() {
if (recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
    txtViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    txtViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}

}
```

AppDatabase code:

```
    @Database(entities = {WorkoutItem.class, ExerciseItem.class, SetItem.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WorkoutDao workoutDao();
    public abstract ExerciseDao exerciseDao();
    public abstract SetDao setDao();

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "DB_NAME")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();

        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

WorkoutAdapter code:

```
    public class WorkoutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkoutAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<WorkoutItem> workoutList;
    private Context context;
    private WorkoutInterface workoutInterface;
    
    public void setWorkoutInterface(WorkoutInterface workoutInterface) {
        this.workoutInterface = workoutInterface;
    }
    public void setWorkoutList(List<WorkoutItem> workoutList){
        this.workoutList = workoutList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public List<WorkoutItem> getWorkoutList() {
        return workoutList;
    }
    public void removeItem(WorkoutItem workoutItem) {
        int position = workoutList.indexOf(workoutItem);
        if (position != -1) {
            workoutList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
    public WorkoutAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_workout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView_workout_name.setText(this.workoutList.get(position).workoutName);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (workoutInterface != null) {
                    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        workoutInterface.onItemClick(workoutList.get(position));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.workoutList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView_workout_name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView_workout_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_workout);

        }

    }
}
```

WorkoutDao code:

```
    @Dao
public interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workoutitem")
    List<WorkoutItem> getAllWorkoutItems();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workoutitem WHERE id = :workoutId")
    WorkoutItem getWorkoutById(int workoutId);
    @Query("UPDATE workoutitem SET position = :newPosition WHERE id = :id")
    void updateWorkoutItemPosition(int id, int newPosition);
    @Update
    void updateWorkoutItem(WorkoutItem workoutItem);

    @Insert
    void insertWorkoutItem(WorkoutItem... workoutItems);
    @Delete
    void delete(WorkoutItem workoutItem);
}
```

WorkoutItem code:

```
    @Entity
public class WorkoutItem {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "workout_name")
    public String workoutName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "position")
    public int position;

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public String getWorkoutName() {
        return workoutName;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```